# best way to show share and favorite button icon?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I noticed some iOS app has favorite button  and share button as attachment. I designed two icons. but they looks so ugly, What's the best way to show share and favorite button icon? any system icon/code to use?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "share" icon is a standard. Use the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` value with the `UIBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` method.

There is no standard for favorites. You will have to create your own.

See the documentation for `UIBarButtonSystemItem` of the list of standard icons you can use with `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Is there any default implementation for Share button? which can show up the ON, Facebook, email,etc. then I do not need redesign them which also contains icons.

Comment: See `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.